# Why fetch Body object can be read only once?

Tags: javascript, standards, fetch-api, specifications

The `fetch` [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-bodyused) states that the readable stream `Body` contains the `Body.bodyUsed` flag which is initially set to `false` and then is set to `true` with a call of any parsing method.

Here's an example:

```
fetch('/some/path', (res) => {
    // res.body.bodyUsed === false
    res.json();
    // res.body.bodyUsed === true
});
```

If you try to call a method like `res.json()` or `res.text()` once again, an exception is thrown.

**The question is**: why that behavior is used? Why not to allow parsing that readable stream as many times as one wants? I found no explanation of the matter.

PS. In Chrome (and maybe other browsers), that flag is accessible as `res.body.locked`.

Comment: `why that behavior is used?` because it's easy to allow multiple use using `Response.clone()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone

Comment: It would require the body to be stored in the `res` object.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, but that doesn't answer the next logical question: why to restrict it in first place and implementing `clone()` instead.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! Is that the only reason?

Comment: @PhilFilippak _"but that doesn't answer the next logical question: why to restrict it in first place and implementing `clone()` instead."_ How do you propose to identify when a `ReadableStream` read procedure is complete?

Comment: `clone` cannot be used (it throws) if the body has been consumed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question is: why that behavior is used? Why not to allow parsing
>   that readable stream as many times as one wants?

It is possible to  read `Response.body` more than once by using [`Response.clone()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-clone)

Comment: Yes, I know about this. But that does not explain why restricting the most obvious way to read it.

Comment: @PhilFilippak The simplest explanation would be to identify when the `Response.body` is "drained", though note that concept also applies to `Request` and to some extent compatibility and corresponding implementation with [Streams specification](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/), see [Proposed backward-incompatible change: requiring cloning all requests/responses #61](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/61). Perhaps consider filing an [issue](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues) asking the authors and contributors to the specification for clarification as to your specific inquiry.

Comment: With the concept of Streams it makes sense now. Thank you for the explanation. Could you mention Streams in your initial answer, please, so I could check it as accepted?

Comment: @PhilFilippak What precisely should be mentioned  at Answer about Streams specification at Answer? The `Fetch` specification itself contains a section about streams at  [2.9. Streams](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#streams)

Comment: That requests and responses are required to be compatible with Streams to the extent of being marked as read and parsed once they are. Well, the link to that part of specification will do, too.

Comment: @PhilFilippak You include a link to the specification at OP, a link to the specification relevant to streams is included at comments, at this Answer. Specifications require careful reading as they are technical documents. Can only defer to the specification linked at the Question itself. The Answer appears to be adequate as to the question of reading a `Response.body` twice. Not entirely certain what could be included in Answer other than read and re-read the specification and links included therein.

Comment: @PhilFilippak Note, the authors and contributors to the Fetch and Streams specifications are diligent as to maintaining clarity of the concepts conveyed in the specification. If, from your perspective, the content lacks clarity, would again, suggest filing an issue specifying which word, phrase, sentence or section of the specification is not clear to you; for the authors and contributors to the specification be able to address the issue and potentially provide greater clarity for all readers of the specifications.