# Why is object.value not working in my if statement in try-catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, async-await, try-catch

I created this custom hook in my React app:

```
const useMyHook = (url: string) => {
  const [fetchState, setFetchState] = useState('pending');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchResponse = async () => {
      try {
        setFetchState('loading');
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const obj = await response.json();
        console.log('obj token', obj.token !== undefined); // this returns true

        const isValidHeader = response.headers
          .get('Content-Type')
          ?.includes('application/json');

        if (response.ok && isValidHeader && obj.token !== undefined) {
          console.log(await response.json());
          setFetchState('succes');
        }

        return null;
      } catch (error) {
        setFetchState('failed');
        console.error(error);
      }
      return null;
    };

    fetchResponse();
  }, []);

  return fetchState;
};

export default useMyHook;
```

When I test this function it's returning `'failed'`?

If I remove the condition `&& obj.token !== undefined` it's working fine and returns `'succes`?

What's wrong, why is the `obj.token` not working here?

Comment: how do we check ? can it be reproduced ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should provide the url for testing.

Your function fails because of this line. `console.log(await response.json());`

response.json() can be used only once, and you used it before. So you should replace that line with `console.log(obj);` You can read more about that [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742251/why-fetch-body-object-can-be-read-only-once).

You should also read errors better.
[image: Error]

Ps. succes -> success